# How to start some Method every 20 days (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone Applicarion I need to implement logic to start some Method every 20 days, how can I implement this?

```
public void Method()
{
//some logic

}
```

**Update**
For example I can fix the first start of some method, then every start of application I will fix the current date time and them calculate the differens, and if the difference between the last and first sstart of some method will be more than 30 days I will start Method(). So how can I calculate the difference (days)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps push notifications could help here, but the user has to click on the toast notifications to trigger your app and therefore your method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to know if it's 20 (or more?) days since you last performed an action in your app.

Let's assume that you save the date to calculate from as a `DateTime` called `savedDate`. (I'm assuming you can put this in and retrieve from IsolatedStorage without issue.)
Then you can just do a simple test against the current date:

```
if (saveddate.Date.AddDays(20) <= DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
{
    // Do your every 20 days action here 
    // and then probably reset savedDate to the current date?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not easily!

The best fit for this is to use a Scheduled Agent - but this runs ever 30 minutes approximately - so you would need to keep track of the last run time and act accordingly.

The other issue with this is that if the app that is associated with the scheduled task is not run at least ever 14 days the task is disabled.

HTH,
Rupert.

Answer (score 0):

What about a push notification. You let the server take care of this. When the time is ready it sends a notification to the phone which does things accordingly.

Edit:
To find the difference you can do something like this

```
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);  
if(span.Days >= 20)
   Method();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last time the method was ran in [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), and then use the Scheduled Agent to run every 30min:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastTimeRanFromIsolatedStorage) > TimeSpan.FromDays(20))
{
   Method();
}
```

Comment: Scheduled Agents will stop running if you don't use the main app in 14 days (IIRC)